# Mongodb export csv in sorted order

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to export an entire MongoDB collection sorted by some of the fields.  I'm led to believe that the following should work:

```
$ mongoexport --csv -d my_db -c my_collection -f field1.subfield,field2.subfield -o d.csv -q '{$query:{},$orderby:{"field1.subfield":1}}'
```

Unfortunately, this only exports one record in the collection (there are 18478 records) and the data exported is blank.  Leaving the $orderby blank, like so,

```
$ mongoexport --csv -d my_db -c my_collection -f field1.subfield,field2.subfield -o d.csv -q '{$query:{},$orderby:{}}'
```

, exports the whole collection the way I want, so clearly the orderby clause is wrong.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

mongoexport utility does not expect you to sort data.